# NDIS Miniport driver failed to load on XP OS during a particular scenario

Tags: windows, ndis

Our USB composite device will support different functionality.one interface will support Network functionality.
We are developing different NDIS miniport versions for different OS.(NDIS 5.1 for XP, NDIS 6.1 for Vista and NDIS 6.20 for Windows7 OS).
We have one test case as shown below:
1) After loading all drivers(serial and NDIS) open any serial interface using Hyperterminal
2) Do Some communication (enter AT command etc)
3) Unplug the device with out closing Hyper terminal
4) Replug the device to the same USB port.

For the above test scenario, NDIS miniport driver fails to load after step-4(error code 31) on XP OS.NDIS Miniport drivers' Initialize handler is not called. 
On other OS i am not able to reproduce this issue.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're not releasing all of the resources you hold upon unlpug. Check your unplug handler code.